# Google Cloud DNS not working for me

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I did the following steps but my domain was not getting resolved:

1. I created a zone (file) in Google Cloud -> Networking -> Cloud DNS using the right DNS name for the domain.
2. I put these NS as shown in Registrar Setup into my domain registrar:

   ```
   ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com
   ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com
   ```
3. I waited hours until the NS changes kicked in and verified in whois.
4. My domain was getting resolved.

Did I miss any other steps?  I could not figure out so that I abandoned the Google Cloud DNS and went with my registrar's DNS and it is working now.

Comment: it usually updates in under 5 minutes for me, but it took 2 hours today

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure everything is spelled correctly.**

i had trouble the other day. getting the domain to resolve while using google cloud services dns.

after waiting for about 30 hours, i double checked my work and found out that i had misspelled my domain name when i set up the dns zone.

usually the google dns entries resolve pretty quickly, especially if the domain is purchased from domains.google.com

the trailing . at the end has not been necessary for me.  infact, when using domains.google.com, the trailing dot is automatically removed when entered as the custom dns-server.

Answer (score 0):

All the NS you have listed doesn't have trailing . towards the end, as in
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.

Would you be able to try updating the NS with your Registrar?

Comment: I can't really try that now as the domain went live.  Can someone please verify?  I have never had to put trailing periods with any registrars in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already add a record (A record) to map the external IP address to your domain?

Your domain should be already working if you have all the records that are needed (and properly copied the NS record to your domain provider). However, for some time, you may need to wait for the propagation to change. See this link: https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#propagation_of_changes

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Platform, Cloud DNS has two requirements and I think you forgot the "A" record.

Requirements:

1. domain name from your domain name registrar.
2. IP address to point the A record of your zone. A valid IP address can be a server you already have running with an IP address you can point to.

To create an "A" record check below link:
https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_new_record